# Sum function in sql query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have this table `Student` :

> 1. Id (int , primary key identity)
> 2. Name (varchar(20))
> 3. Score (int)
> 4. RecordDate (DateTime)

I need to select all the columns of this table plus an extra column that represents the 'Sum' of 'Score' column depending of the `Name` of the student.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
select S.Id,S.Name ,S.Score ,S.RecordDate, ( select Sum(Score) from Student where Name= S.Name) as All_Student_Score
 from Student S;
```

How can I change this query ?

Comment: Dont mix up the databases

Comment: Are you looking this in SQL-Server or mysql or both?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use a `JOIN`:

    SELECT S.*,
           T.All_Student_Score
    FROM Student S
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, SUM(Score) All_Student_Score
                FROM Student) T
        ON S.Name = T.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
select Id,Name ,Score ,RecordDate, sum(score) over(partition by name) as All_Student_Score from Student S
```

Comment: You are right, hadn't noticed it. But your query is still wrong though

Comment: Just noticing that he is asking sum for individual name.. thanks, since alias he mentioned as 'All_student_score' i got confused...

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works for your requirement.

```
select Id, 
       Name,
       Score,
       RecordDate,
       sum(score) over( partition by name ) as All_Student_Score 
  from Student;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because no one showed you that your own solution should work if you just alias your table in your sub query you can do the following:

```
select
     S.Id,S.Name
     ,S.Score
     ,S.RecordDate
     ,(select Sum(Score) from Student s2 where s2.Name= S.Name) as All_Student_Score
from
     Student S;
```